# Sum results inside while loop

Tags: php

I have following code inside while loop (displaying results from database into table):

```
$count = count($prvi_podatak_ispis); 
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i){
        $sum = $prvi_podatak_ispis[$i] - $prvi_podatak_ispis[$i + 1]; 
        //echo "<font color='red'>" . $sum . '</font><br />';
}

$count2 = count($drugi_podatak_ispis);
for ($k=0; $k < $count2 - 1 ; ++$k) { 
    $sum2 = $drugi_podatak_ispis[$k] - $drugi_podatak_ispis[$k + 1];
    //echo "<font color='blue'>" . $sum2 . '</font><br />';
}

$count3 = count($treci_podatak_ispis);
for ($o=0; $o < $count3 - 1; ++$o) { 
    $sum3 = $treci_podatak_ispis[$o] - $treci_podatak_ispis[$o + 1];
    //echo "<font color='black'>" . $sum3 . '</font><br />';
}

$count4 = count($cetvrti_podatak_ispis);
for ($p=0; $p < $count4 - 1; ++$p) { 
    $sum4 = $cetvrti_podatak_ispis[$p] - $cetvrti_podatak_ispis[$p + 1];
    //echo "<font color='green'>" . $sum4 . '</font><br />'; 
}
```

If I uncomment `echo` inside any **for loop**, results are fine. But I am trying to sum all results foreach displayed result from database like:

`$final = $sum + $sum2 + $sum3 + $sum4;`

When I use `echo $final;`, first result is 0 and I get errors **Notice: Undefined variable: sum2, sum, sum3, sum4** probably for that first result. Where am I wrong?

Comment: 1/ Are you sure all your `XXXX[$i]` and `XXXX[$i + 1]` (same for $k, $o and $p) exist? 2/ What happen if you add `$sum = 0;`, `$sum2 = 0`, etc. BEFORE each for loop, do you still get an error in your `$final` ?

Comment: I guess you want to sum up during the loops, in this case you would have to use `$sum += ...`. But in this case your sums would be just the first array element minus the last, so you wouldn't need the loops at all. What are you trying to sum up in the end? Could you use `array_sum()`?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Okay, but first $final result is 0... But it can't be 0

Comment: @Pablo look the anwser :) The problem is : 1/ You don't initiate the $sum BEFORE the for loop with `$sum = 0;` 2/ Then you erase each sum with `$sum = ... - ....`, you need to to `$sum += ... - ...`; This way it should works

Comment: where is the `while` loop? What variables are defined beforeattempting to sum these variables?

Comment: @RamRaider Well there is query for selecting results from database, then there is while loop for display that results.. Inside that while loop I set for loops above

Answer (score 3):

Declare a variable as global like string variable $str="" or integer $i=0 and you can access it's in outside the for

In your code sum1,sum2 etc sum variable are local for in For loop that scope are end at the loop are end

You should declare variable at the global it access

Comment: At the last of loop after initialize $final=$sum it work @Pablo

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `sum variables` globaly like `$sum = $sum2 = $sum3 = $sum4 = 0` . It will work

Answer (score 1):

Your only adding the elements in each loop, not creating an overall sum of the values. Set the value to 0 outside the loop and use `+=` to add the value each time...

```
$sum = 0;
$count = count($prvi_podatak_ispis); 
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i){
        $sum += $prvi_podatak_ispis[$i] - $prvi_podatak_ispis[$i + 1]; 
        //echo "<font color='red'>" . $sum . '</font><br />';
}
```

Repeat this pattern throughout.

Comment: Okay, I dont have errors anymore, but my first result into table is 0, but it can't be 0.

Comment: Do you have some data I can try it on?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a sum variables to 0 and update this only variable in each `for` loop

```
$sum = 0;
$count = count($prvi_podatak_ispis); 
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i){
        $sum = $prvi_podatak_ispis[$i] - $prvi_podatak_ispis[$i + 1]; 
        //echo "<font color='red'>" . $sum . '</font><br />';
}

$count2 = count($drugi_podatak_ispis);
for ($k=0; $k < $count2 - 1 ; ++$k) { 
    $sum+= $drugi_podatak_ispis[$k] - $drugi_podatak_ispis[$k + 1];
    //echo "<font color='blue'>" . $sum2 . '</font><br />';
}

$count3 = count($treci_podatak_ispis);
for ($o=0; $o < $count3 - 1; ++$o) { 
    $sum+= $treci_podatak_ispis[$o] - $treci_podatak_ispis[$o + 1];
    //echo "<font color='black'>" . $sum3 . '</font><br />';
}

$count4 = count($cetvrti_podatak_ispis);
for ($p=0; $p < $count4 - 1; ++$p) { 
    $sum+= $cetvrti_podatak_ispis[$p] - $cetvrti_podatak_ispis[$p + 1];
    //echo "<font color='green'>" . $sum4 . '</font><br />'; 
}
```

And now, what you need $final=`$sum`.

Comment: I did that, next problem is that I have first result 0 at table as  $final variable

Comment: You mean, $sum = 0 ?

Comment: No, displaying first result. Read my question please